# how to pass a pointer to physical memory from kernel space to user space and map it to virtual space

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, linux-kernel

I'm working on a driver-like code for a PCI device which. The communication is done through a buffer, i.e. I write to a buffer and device grabs data from it. Device writes to a buffer and I grad data from it. Here is where the problem occurs. In order for a device to write to this buffer it needs to have its physical address (not virtual one). My boss told me it is possible to do it if I write a kernel module and allocate memory using `kmalloc`.

Here are my questions.
How do I get access to this buffer from a user space, i.e. how do I pass a pointer to this buffer from a kernel space to a user space? Since all addresses in user space are virtual addresses, how do I convert a physical pointer to this buffer to a virtual one? As far as I understand I need to use `ioctl` but I don't how.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If I was to do this I would probably take a look at the DRM in the graphics drivers

Comment: Implement `mmap` in your driver to do that. Read [Linux Device Drivers](http://www.xml.com/ldd/chapter/book/ch13.html) for more details.

Comment: @kaylum That's the book I've been reading for the past week. I did look at the relevant chapters for my case and I don't think `mmap` is the right approach. The trick is that I'm the one who has to allocate a buffer, however in order for the device to write to it, it needs a physical address of the buffer.

Comment: @doron Can you elaborate more, I'm not sure I know what you are talking about.

Comment: But your actual question is "how do I pass a pointer to this buffer from a kernel space to a user space". That is exactly what `mmap` will achieve.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a PCI device then it already has a physical address than you need to map. Your device has a class and a subclass id. Spin through all of your pci devices until you get a match on your class and subclass id then pull the bus address from that.

You then map the physical address using mmap

[C++ app to talk to an FPGA over PCI in userland using mmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6874945/c-app-to-talk-to-an-fpga-over-pci-in-userland-using-mmap)

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use Netlink Socket API. This link could be of help to you [How to use netlink socket to communicate with a kernel module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3299386/how-to-use-netlink-socket-to-communicate-with-a-kernel-module)

Comment: Thanks for the response but this is not exactly what I'm looking for. As I said communication is done through a buffer and a user is responsible for buffer allocation. However a device needs to have a physical address for this buffer in order to read/write data from/to it.